# Install make on chromebook developer mode

Tags: linux, makefile

I just got a chromebook and I put it in developer mode. I'm trying to install software on it, but I realized I don't have the command "make", so it's very hard for me to install programs. I have the "make" program downloaded but whenever I try to do ./configure, it says permission denied. I'm very new to this, so please explain why I have to do ./configure and why does it say permission denied. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`./configure` is a script distributed with many source packages which automatically tries to figure out the best settings for compiling a program on your computer.

If it tells you "permission denied" when you try to execute it, try `chmod +x configure` first, to give the script *execute permissions*.